# mapping on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

find the image inside the circle $|z-2|=2$  under the mapping $f(z)=\frac{z}{2z-8}$, I don't know what it turns into, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Mobius transformation.  They are determined by what they do to $3$ points. And they map generalized circles to generalized circles.

We can see that $0\mapsto 0,4\mapsto\infty$ and $2+2i\mapsto (2+2i)/(-4+4i)=(1+i)/(-2+2i)=2i$.

Thus the circle goes to the  line through $0$ and $2i$.
That's the $y$-axis.

Now note that $2\mapsto -1/2$.  We conclude that the transformation maps the interior of the cirle to the left half plane.